# Cookie и PHP

Tags: opera, php, cookie

Добрый день! У меня есть код, который создаёт новый кук и при разных условиях принимает разные значения.
Устанавливаю так:

```
setcookie('data', "", time()+3600);
```

Присваиваю значения:

```
if(...){
    $_COOKIE[data] = "ok";
echo $_COOKIE[data];

} else {
    $_COOKIE[data] = "bad";
    echo $_COOKIE[data];
}
```

Печатаю кук только для теста.

Проблема вот в чём: кук просто не сохраняется (проверил в Opera, Chrome)(открываю настройки смотрю а там пусто, так же смотрел через Opera Dragonfly и отладчик хрома), подскажите что делать то?

P.S>>На одной странице(там где печатаю) - всё гуд. На остальных кука вообще нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записываем

```
<?php SetCookie("data","value", time()+3600 , '/', '.example.com') ?>
```

Читаем

```
<?php $cookies = $_COOKIE['data']; echo ($cookies); ?>
```

Работает во всех браузерах

Comment: А разве нельзя присвоить значение определённому куку:
`$_COOKIE[data] = "ok";`
Мне просто только так подходит, потому что если исп. ваш вариант получаем ошибку:
*Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ....*

Comment: $_COOKIE['data'] это выгрузка куков из система, для сохранения используется функция SetCookie();
вы можете записать сразу несколько значении SetCookie("data","ok"); SetCookie("data2","value"); и тд, проверять куки можно таким образом if ($_COOKIE['data'] == "ok") { echo "OK"; }  else { echo "BAD"; }